# Value check in a dataframe

Tags: python

I want to validate each value in a dataframe with multiple columns and datatype and get a count of  instances for each column where value is either 1,2,3.

The dataframe has check columns which show 1,2,3 based if value in original data column is either bad, good or blank.

sample dataset

[image: sample dataset]

> list_DE = []
> list_C = []
> list_D = []
> list_B = []
> header = ["Field Name ","Blank Values","Correct Values", "Defects"]
> defects = 0
> blanks = 0
> corrects = 0
> for col in df.columns:
> for i in [col]:
> if i == 3:
> blanks + 1
> elif i == 2:
> correct + 1
> elif i == 1:
> defects + 1
> list_DE.append(col)
> list_C.append(corrects)
> list_D.append(defects)
> list_B.append(blanks)
>
> Acc_df =  pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list_DE,list_B,list_C,list_D)), columns = header)

I am getting
Field Name    Blank Values    Correct Values  Defects
0   Contact_id       0          0                  0
1   Contact_name     0          0              0

I am expecting
Field Name    Blank Values    Correct Values  Defects
0   Contact_id       1          4                  3
1   Contact_name     1          4              3